# PHP: session variable lost on clicking form submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, session

When I click form submit button session variable lost and it shows message that session is not set. I have another confusion that it has only problem when I set session of login variable or those variables which are set in other page of my site.
When I set some random session variable on the top of this page it works fine and session variable does not lose anymore. I have also checked some other related links in stack overflow but nothing found solution

**Here is the code of addProduct.php page**

```
        <?php

    //var_dump($_SESSION);
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']))) {

        echo "session is not set";
    }
    else {
        //header("location:index.php");
        echo "session is set";
        //$user_email=$_SESSION['user_email'];



    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <form action="addproduct.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="name" value="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

        </form>


        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
           // $_SESSION['user_email']=$_SESSION['user_email'];
            echo $name;
        }
        ?>
    <?php }
    ?>
```

**Code of index.php (header file) page from where I get into this page**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("db.php");
    ?>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="index.php">Home</a></br></br>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login']) ) {
    if($_SESSION['user_status']=="admin")
    {

    ?>
    <a href="index.php?page=addproduct">Post an Ad</a></br></br>
    <?php }
    }

    ?>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_fname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_lname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
    {
    ?>
    <a href="index.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_fname'] . " " . $_SESSION['user_lname'] . " " . $_SESSION['user_status']; ?></a></br></br>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a></br></br>
    <a href="UserSignup.php">SignIn</a></br></br>
    <?php }
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_fname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_lname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
    {
    ?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></br></br>
    <?php }
    ?>
    <div id="content">
        <?php


        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $p=$_GET['page'];

            $page =  $p . ".php";
            //echo $page;
            if(file_exists($page))
            {include($page);
            }
            elseif($page=="")
                echo "this is home page";
            else
            {echo "Not found";}
        }

        else
        {
            include ("showAds.php");
        }
        ?>

    </div>










    </body>
    </html>
```

**Code of login.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_fname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_lname']) && isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
        else
        {

    ?>

    <html>

    <head><title>Login</title></head>
    <body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="USER EMAIL" REQUIRED>
        <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="USER PASSWORD" REQUIRED>

        <input type="submit" name="Go" value="SUBMIT!" placeholder="USER NAME" REQUIRED>
        </br></br><a href="UserSignup.php">SignIn with new account</a></br>



    </form>

    <?php
    include("db.php");
    /*if(isset($_POST['Go'])) {    SIGNUP
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        echo $user_name . "<br>";
        echo $user_email . "<br>";
        echo $user_password . "<br>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user(user_name,user_email,user_password) VALUE ('$user_name','$user_email','$user_password')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            echo "stored";
            header("location:http://localhost/window.php");
        }
        else
        {
          die(mysqli_error($sql));
        }
    }*/
    if(isset($_POST['Go']))
    {
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];//real_escape_string
        $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $login_query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_password='$user_password'";
        $run=mysqli_query($conn,$login_query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)

        {
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ecommerce.user WHERE user_email='$user_email'");

            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

                $_SESSION['user_fname']=$record['user_fname'];
                $_SESSION['user_lname'] = $record['user_lname'];
                $_SESSION['user_status'] = $record['user_status'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $record['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_password'] = $record['user_password'];

            }


            $_SESSION['user_email']=$user_email;
            $_SESSION['login']="true";

           //echo $_SESSION['user_fname'] . $_SESSION['user_lname'];


            header("location:index.php");
            exit();
        }
        else
            echo "<p style='color: red; margin-top: -28px;'>User name or password incorrect</p>";
    }




    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: `addProduct.php` is file where I am getting problem. `index.php` is header file

Comment: What do you mean by header.file will this file be included in `addProduct.php` before you access the session variable? i guess not! So please try to add the `session_start();` method in `addProduct.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you showed in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132731/php-session-variable-lost-on-clicking-form-submit-button) which was marked as an exact duplicate of this one:

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\showAds.php on line 2

Your `showAds.php` page which you didn't include, (most likely) contains `session_start();` and it should be removed from inside that file.

`index.php` has an include and `session_start();`

```
else
    {
        include ("showAds.php");
    }
```

So one of your `if` statements failed.

That is why you're getting that error.

All pages using sessions require that `session_start();` be included and should be the first line of your script, which isn't shown in `addProduct.php`.

Also make sure you're not outputting before header. If you are, consult the following on how to fix it:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: It start working but also shows error `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\addproduct.php on line 2`

Comment: @ImranHasan make sure there isn't another included file. What I suggest you do is to find all instances of `session_start();` in all your files and the ones you're including. You need to remove `session_start();` from inside all included files and only use `session_start();` in the actual files that are loaded and at the top of your script and make sure there are no spaces before your opening `<?php` tag and not outputting before header also. Included files should not contain `session_start();`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `session_start();` in your addProduct.php to be able to access session contents!